# How to add a new tab to Case Activity tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, casefeed, app-builder

In the detail page for a `Case` in Salesforce, there are tabs for activity feeds.
In the screenshot below, they are `All Updates`, `Call Logs`, `Text Posts` and `Status Changes`. (in the mid-centre of the screenshot)

I want to add a new tab to this, and render an Aura component in that. Is something like this possible? Please help. Any leads will help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to add a new tab.

1) Setup > Object Manager > Case > Case Page Layout

2) Select the layout > Click Feed View on the very top (Blue bar)

3) In Feed View > Scroll down to Feed Filter Options

Then proceed to add the items you need.